# Почему при использовании cout приложение на С++ закрывается в Windows XP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, windows-xp

Консольное приложение создано в Visual Studio C++ 2015. Windows 7.

Настройки проекта:

Набор инструментов платформы: Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)

Библиотека времени выполнения: Многопоточная (/MT)

Запускаю exe-шник. Из папки Release в проекте.
На Windows 7 все работает.
Перекинул на другой комп под Windows XP запускается и сразу закрывается. Видно только как консоль мигнула(т.е. открылась и закрылась).
Если использовать printf вместо cout(и при этом cout закоментировать), то работает и под 7 и под XP. Почему cout не работает под XP? И как сделать, что бы работал?

Вот код проекта:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(void) {

    cout << "\nHello Windows XP! From cout!" << endl;      //don't work in Windows XP 

    //printf("\nHello Windows XP! From printf!\n");          //work Windows XP

    _getch();//и system(pause) тоже не помогает в Windows XP
}
```

Comment: а что за  _getch()?

Comment: "Мигнул" - т.е. не работает `_getch()`? И еще - у вас есть разница между `cout` и `printf` в том, где расположен `\n` - в принципе, может играть роль при буферизации... Поставьте и в `cout` для чистоты эксперимента в конце. И все же еще раз - у вас `_getch()` работает?

Comment: и main ничего не возвращает и _getch неизвестная функция. Результат налицо...

Comment: а может быть под 7 запускается с под студии, а в xp - просто с браузера?