# Как включить поддержку Windows XP в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, windows-xp

На одном компьютере на Windows 7 установлены Visual Studio 2008 и Visual Studio 2015.

В Visual Studio 2008  и в Visual Studio 2015 созданы консольные проекты с одним и тем же простейшим кодом.

Код такой:

Файл stdafx.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Файл Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void main(void) {
    cout << "sqrt(4.0) = " << sqrt(4.0) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Свойства проекта созданного на Visual Studio 2015:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства проекта в Visual Studio 2008 не привожу так как с ним все ок.

Компилирую проекты в обеих студиях.

Переношу из папки **Release** получившиеся exe файлы проектов на комп под Windows XP.

Файл.exe который скопилирован на Visual Studio 2008 запускается и выводит результат ждет нажатия клавиши. Все ок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А тот который сделан на  Visual Studio 2015, после запуска на XP происходит следующее: открывается консоль ничего не выведено(черная консоль) и сразу закрывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: по-моему это дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147826/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-cout-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-windows-xp

Comment: Под windows, если терминал закрывается сразу после запуска консольного приложения без сообщений об ошибке -  это первый признак отсутствия нужных dll. Почему windows не может просто напечатать, каких библиотек ему не хватает - для меня загадка, но в вашем случае, вероятно, не хватает распространяемых пакетов со стандартной библиотекой с++ (в ms vs нет обратной совместимости). Если это так, то вам сюда: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: @Ariox На картинке рантайм линкуется статически и исполняемый файл по идее не должен требовать установки чего-то еще.